# How do I remove all items but the first from the android program stack by button press?

Tags: java, android

Rather than clicking the back button several times after enabling the below code. I'd like instead to simply click one button and have all other items on the stack removed and the user to be returned to the primary stack item. How do I do this?

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(it);
```

Where `MainActivity` is your primary stack activity.

Hope it helps!